# sed -r not compatible with -i

Tags: sed, rhel

I have a simple text file:

```
>cat a
A=B
```

Using sed, I am trying to change this to:

```
setenv A B
```

My sed command which doesn't work is :

```
>sed -ir 's/([^\=]+)\=(.*)/setenv \1 \2/' a
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

However the same command words when I remove the -i option:

```
>sed -r 's/([^\=]+)\=(.*)/setenv \1 \2/' a
setenv A B
```

I don't have this problem when I use basic regular expression:

```
>sed -ir 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/setenv \1 \2/' a
>cat a
setenv A B
```

My sed version is :

```
>sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-i` option of GNU Sed is somewhat non-conformant in that it can *optionally* take an argument specifying a backup suffix

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

So `sed -ir 's/pattern/replacement' a` means "edit file `a` in place, making a backup file `ar`" rather than "edit file `a` in place, using extended regular expression syntax"

You want either

```
sed -i -r 's/pattern/replacement' a
```

or (less clear IMHO)

```
sed -ri 's/pattern/replacement' a
```

Comment: `-r` is also not portable. Try with `-E` which seems to be more widely supported; or use traditional regex in `pattern`. (If it doesn't contain any regex metacharacters, the `-E` or `-r` doesn't do anything useful anyway.)